# the voice that talks to me from my computer sounds strange

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

My Mac desktop has Mountain Lion osx 10.8.5 installed. Since installing it, the voice that talks to me from my computer sounds strange.

Why has it gone from sounding clean and advanced to . . . weird?

Comment: "the voice that talks to me from my computer sounds like a retarded deaf woman"  I want a audio capture of that.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question and went to click the link, I heard this in my mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Me-VhC9ieh0

Answer (score 0):

You can select text-to-speech voices in System Preferences. I can't remember what the particular preference pane was named back in Mountain Lion, but today (El Capitan 10.11.x) it's called "Dictation & Speech".

From there, you should be able to optionally download additional high-quality voices (free from Apple), but be forewarned, the high-quality voice downloads are pretty big (like, around a gigabyte each, if I recall correctly).